# Lit-element - :host selector is not triggering render on Safari

Tags: css, safari, shadow-dom, lit-element

In a project I'm working on, I have this LitElement component, which is **absolute-positioned** and determines its **left or top** locations according to its reactive properties.

I've encountered a problem in **Safari** only, including iOS Safari/Chrome/Firefox. The element has updated its shadow styles, but in the view it does not move at all. I realized its a render issue when I found that **when the cursor hovers the element**, or exits the browser view, the element pops to the expected location.

I managed to reproduce the problem with a simpler code:

***my-elem.ts:***

```js
import { LitElement, html, property, customElement, css } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-elem')
export class MyElem extends LitElement {
    @property({ type: Number, reflect: true })
    left: number = 30

    static get styles() {
        return css`
            :host { position: absolute; }
            div { position: absolute; }
        `;
    }

    render() {
        return html`
            <style>
                :host { left: ${this.left}px; }
            </style>
            <div> Hello </div>
        `;
    }
}
```

***index.html:***

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="my-elem.ts"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <my-elem id="my-elem" left="50"></my-elem>
    <button id="move-btn">move</button>
    <script>
        const elem = document.getElementById('ma-elem');
        const moveBtn = document.getElementById('move-btn');
        moveBtn.onclick = function() {
            elem.left += 30;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I found that this happens only on `:host` selector. If the shadowed styling updates the `div`'s `left`, it renders without any problems.

I wish to avoid forcing the browser to layout/paint, due to performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is that you are trying to use an expression inside a style element in your render template.

The LitElement guide mentions that using them that way [has limitations and can cause performance issues](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#in-a-style-element). I think your problem is just facing one of them so you should remove that style element.

As an alternative, since you want to affect the host element, you can actually do this in an easier way if you just don't use a property but style the host directly.

So when using `my-elem` the code would look like:

```
<my-elem style="left: 30px;"></my-elem>
```

This is because styles applied to `:host` in shadow DOM have less priority than those applied to it using classes or the style attribute by its parent.

Alternatively, if you really want to keep the property, you can [create property accessors](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#accessors) for the `left` property and set the style to the host from there like this:

```js
export class MyElem extends LitElement {
  // other code
  
  set left(value) {
    const oldValue = this.left;
    this._left = value;
    this.style.setProperty('left', `${value}px`)
    this.requestUpdate('left', oldValue);
  }
  
  get left() {
    return this._left;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I do wish to keep it because in the actual code the left location is calculated using other data.

Comment: @SilberGuy that's perfectly fine, just remember that for that specific type of styles using an attribute is not always necessary. That knowledge might be helpful when developing future components . By the way, if this answer resolved your problem, please consider accepting the answer 